# Include Pre-Formatted content in ACUMATICA Report Writer

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a simple one page report for quoting an opportunity from Acumatica ERP which is working fine.

However, my customer has a standard boilerplate page for terms and conditions. They would like that to be appended to all quotes being generated. But, I don't see a way of adding a pre-formatted page to a report at execution time.

I can do it in code. Create a button that calls the report, and then through .NET code add the conditions page that way. But it seems like this functionality might exist within the report writer itself.

Does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the report footer section, this is the appropriate place to add the boilerplate page.  Report footer prints as the last page.  You could create a PNG file, in case your boilerplate page has graphics.  Then embed the image file into the report footer section.

Be sure to set Page Break property as true

Comment: If it's an image, make sure it's not scaled or the text quality will be degraded.